# Upload image to this domain and also a subdomain

Tags: php, cross-domain, image-uploading

I have an image uploading script which works fine when uploading an image to the domain it's on, but I also need to upload the same image to an alternate subdomain.

Here's the bit of the code I'm having trouble with.

```
$filename = "../../images/home-features/" . $imagename;
$filename2 = "/var/www/vhosts/domain.org/httpdocs/images_home/features/" . $imagename;
imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,60);
imagejpeg($tmp,$filename2,60);
```

It's the second of the two which is not uploading. I don't get any errors - it's as if it has worked but then the image is not there.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does imagejpeg return? My guess would be that there are some permissions problems or that the path is wrong

Comment: I think imagejpeg is a php function for creating a jpeg file...

Comment: That is correct. What is the return value? According to the manual: "Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure."

Comment: Ah... sorry! I'm tired... let me look!

Comment: I've changed the second imagejpeg function to a copy as suggested by @nl-x and that is returning false.

Comment: $php_errormsg returns blank too!

Answer (score 0):

i dont know exactly why the second image isnt coming through the same resource. maybe the resource needs rewinding/resetting.

But WHY let the server do the same work all over again? Just copy the first file as the second!

```
copy($filename, $filename2);
```

ps. did you check the directory for the second file is writable?

Comment: I See what you mean with the copying rather than redoing the work. Thanks for the tip. Still no luck though. The images_home and the features directory both have their permissions set to `rwx rwx rwx`. This should be ok, right?

Comment: Further to that, the copy function is returning false.

Comment: Check your error log as to why copy is returning false

Comment: open_basedir restriction in effect is the error message

Comment: It means that your script is not allowed to edit/delete/create files outside the openbasedir. This is a setting that could be in your php.ini or overruled inside some .htaccess or httpd.conf. to solve the problem you need to gave access to the file with the setting, or to be allowed to overrule the setting in a .htaccess. are you allowed to do this?